# Working with Excel using Pandas without changing format and performing operations

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I want to read the below excel and have to work on some of the column that is in green bold type color columns(col1,2 and so on). suppose want to replace the text from some column .. How to do that ? Also, I want that color, font structure of excel to be maintained , Is It possible in Pandas ? 
Attaching Image and pasting content as well...

```
This is the starting point .                                    

Row1        01.06.2018 to 30.06.2018                            
Row 2       Hello                           
Row 3       This is 3rd row                         
Row 4       ABCD004                         

No. Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9
3   123 Abc some_data   some_value  some_value  some_value  some_data   some_data   some_data
4   345 And saome_data  some_value  some_value  some_data   some_data   some_data   some_data
5   678 Add some_data   some_value  some_value  some_data   some_data   some_data   some_data
```

Output Excel:- `col6` value changed to VALID DATA , without changing any excel format(color,font etc)

Also, if the exact format can not be maintained, any nearby solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading data out of Excel and into a Pandas DataFrame object will not keep the font and color formatting of Excel. You can do many transformations on the data once it is in a dataframe, but then you will need to write it back out to Excel where you can re-apply your formatting and colors within Excel. Based on your screen shot, I would advise removing the sections above the actual columns when working with it in Pandas, then you can add them in back in Excel, i.e. these ones:

```
This is the starting point .                                    

Row1        01.06.2018 to 30.06.2018                            
Row 2       Hello                           
Row 3       This is 3rd row                         
Row 4       ABCD004
```

That way you have a well-formed dataframe to work with.

```
No. Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9
3   123 Abc some_data   some_value  some_value  some_value  some_data   some_data some_data
4   345 And saome_data  some_value  some_value  some_data   some_data   some_data   some_data
5   678 Add some_data   some_value  some_value  some_data   some_data   some_data   some_data
```

Again, you can do your data transformations in Pandas, then do your colors and table formatting in Excel. Also if this is a one off requirement, you could just do the transformations in Excel and not use Pandas at all. That may be the fastest way to keep your Excel formatting and replacing what you need to.

Not sure how much experience you have with Pandas, but the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) explains the read/write methods and how to do the transformations you asked. Hopefully that helps a little bit, feel free to explain a bit more or break up your problem statement further, if it is unclear.

Comment: I know how to do transformation in Pandas . I am more interested in finding a way that the till “Row 4” can be avoided so that work can be done on below ..If format will vanish its OK .

Comment: @RonyA Yes, you can delete the rows in Excel manually or if you use Pandas, just create a copy of your dataframe by slicing off those rows using the [] operator. I don't have your exact dataframe, but maybe something like: 
    df_copy = df[6:]